# java regex key: value multiple lines

Tags: java, regex

I have this kind of texts:

> **:33:** 88 app 2/8 superman taman, puchong 36100, Malaysia
>
> **:22:** bla bla \bla /bla bla bla
>
> **:32:** 45//dsfd//qdsfqsdf
>
> **:72D:** Example

This example has a form **:key:value**. Value can be on one or multiline.

I tried the regex **(:[0-9]{2}[A-Z]?:)(.*)** but I got just the first line in the multiline value. When I try the option `Pattern.DOTALL`, the result contains all the text for the first key.

What should be the correct Regex?

Comment: Use [`^(:[0-9]{2}[A-Z]?:)(.*)`](https://regex101.com/r/QXKDfT/1) with `Pattern.MULTILINE` modifier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
(?m)^(:\d{2}[A-Z]?:)(.*(?:\r?\n(?!:\d{2}[A-Z]?:).*)*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Oszz1A/1). Do *not* use `Pattern.DOTALL`.

**Details**

- `(?m)^` - matches the start of a line
- `(:\d{2}[A-Z]?:)`  - Group 1:

  - `:` -  a colon
  - `\d{2}`  - 2 digits
  - `[A-Z]?` - 1 or 0 uppercase ASCII letters
  - `:` - a colon
- `(.*(?:\r?\n(?!:\d{2}[A-Z]?:).*)*)` - Group 2:

  - `.*` - the rest of the line (0 or more chars other than line break chars)
  - `(?:\r?\n(?!:\d{2}[A-Z]?:).*)*` - zero or more sequences of:

    - `\r?\n(?!:\d{2}[A-Z]?:)` - a line break (`\r?\n` in Java 8 should be replaced with `\R`) that is not followed with the pattern as used in Group 1
    - `.*` - the rest of the line

In Java, use

```
String pat = "(?m)^(:\\d{2}[A-Z]?:)(.*(?:\r?\n(?!:\\d{2}[A-Z]?:).*)*)";
```

See [Java demo](https://ideone.com/xp22ht):

```
String s = ":33: 88 app 2/8\nsuperman taman, puchong\n36100, Malaysia\n:22: bla bla \\bla /bla\nbla bla\n:32: 45//dsfd//qdsfqsdf\n:72D: Example";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?m)^(:\\d{2}[A-Z]?:)(.*(?:\r?\n(?!:\\d{2}[A-Z]?:).*)*)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println("--- NEXT PAIR ---"); 
    System.out.println("Key:" + matcher.group(1));
    System.out.println("Value:" + matcher.group(2)); 
}
```

Output:

```
--- NEXT PAIR ---
Key::33:
Value: 88 app 2/8
superman taman, puchong
36100, Malaysia
--- NEXT PAIR ---
Key::22:
Value: bla bla \bla /bla
bla bla
--- NEXT PAIR ---
Key::32:
Value: 45//dsfd//qdsfqsdf
--- NEXT PAIR ---
Key::72D:
Value: Example
```

Comment: Thank for your quick answer. Works perfectly