# String value separate by colon for multiple line

Tags: java, string, collections

I want to separate String by colon and store in key value pair in map, below is the string value

```
String s = "1: AFXSD                                        \n" +
    "   2: TNBLO                                                \n" +
    "  13: ONHDSAD                                                 \n" +
    "  51: NONREF                                                           \n" +
    "  25: 213213234                                                    \n" +
    " 32: ASD3123,01                                                    \n" +
    " 5: /ASDAS321                         abc      \n" +
    "      91360070 AVENIDA ENGENHEIRO ARY DE  ABREU LIMA N 900 PORTO ALEGRE\n" +
    "      BRASIL                                                           \n" +
    " 52A: ASDSADDASSA                                                      ";
```

I have tried to split by `split` method with colon but not able to attach if value is in multiple rows, in colon `5:` has value in multiple rows so all values I need to add in 5 key's value with multiple lines as shown format, colon 5: should not come in single line.

Below code I have tried.

Here String `s` is coming from `ma.getText(row, 2).trim()`

```java
int row = 11;
String a = "";
Map<String, String> mp1 = new LinkedHashMap<>();
ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<>();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
int c = 0;

while(!ma.getText(row, 2).trim().equals("")) {
    String s= ma.getText(row, 2).trim();
    if (s.contains(":")) {
    // a = s.split(":")[0];
    // b = s.split(":")[1];
    //// mp1.put(s.split(":")[0], s.split(":")[1]);
        al.add(s);
        c++;
    } else {
        sb.append(al.get(c)).append(s);
        al.add(sb.toString());
        sb = null;
    }
    mp1.put(a, b);
    row++;
}
```

Comment: Your input example shows `String s;`, but your code snippet doesn't refer to `s` anywhere. Does `ma.getText(row, 2).trim()` refer to just e.g. `1: AFXSD`, or to the whole thing (from 1 to 52:, newlines and all)?

Comment: from 1 to 52 all comes in new line, so 5: data has in 3 lines so how can I append that and add in 5: key's value

Comment: Reread my comment. You did not answer it. What would `System.out.println(ma.getText(row, 2).trim())` print the first time through the while loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there are several tasks here:

1. Parse properly the key-value pairs where values may be multiline
2. Build the map from the key-value pairs and resolve possible conflicts.
   Currently, for key `5` there are two entries, and one of them is multiline:

```
 5: NONREF   
 5: /ASDAS321                         abc      
      91360070 AVENIDA ENGENHEIRO ARY DE  ABREU LIMA N 900 PORTO ALEGRE
      BRASIL
```

The data may be parsed using the regular expression `(?m)^ *(\d+:)(.*(?:\n(?! *\d+:).*)*)` as shown in [the online demo](https://regex101.com/r/gTxNNo/1):

- `(?m)` - multi-line modifier, causes `^` and `$` to match the begin/end of each line (not only begin/end of string)
- `*` -- non-captured whitespace before the key
- `(\d+:)` -- 1<sup>st</sup> capturing group: key including at least 1 digit followed by colon `:`
- `(.*(?:\n(?! *\d+:).*)*)` -- 2<sup>nd</sup> capturing group: value:

  - `.*` - any character except for the line terminators matching as many times as possible
  - `(?:\n(?! *\d+:).*)*` -- non-capturing group, matching the previous token  as many times as possible
  - `\n` -- new-line character (may be replaced with `\R` character class in Java to handle other line terminators)
  - `(?! *\d+:)` -- negative lookahead to detect the next key: optional whitespace prefix followed by several digits followed by a colon.

This regular expression is a modified version from [this answer by W. Stribizew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46077414/java-regex-key-value-multiple-lines)

Next, the map *allowing multiple values for the same key* may be created using a stream of `MatchResult` provided by [`Matcher::results`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#results--) method (Java 9+) and appropriate collectors.

```java
Map<String, List<String>> map = Pattern.compile("(?m)^ *(\\d+:)(.*(?:\n(?! *\\d+:).*)*)")
    .matcher(s)
    .results()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        mr -> mr.group(1), // trimmed, key includes the colon
        LinkedHashMap::new,
        Collectors.mapping(mr -> mr.group(2).trim(), Collectors.toList())
    ));
 
    map.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + " | " + v));
```

Output ([demo at Ideone](https://ideone.com/C2Uesm)):

```
1: | [AFXSD]
2: | [TNBLO]
3: | [ONHDSAD]
5: | [NONREF, /ASDAS321                         abc      
      91360070 AVENIDA ENGENHEIRO ARY DE  ABREU LIMA N 900 PORTO ALEGRE
      BRASIL]
25: | [213213234]
32: | [ASD3123,01]
52: | [ASDSADDASSA]
```

---

If a plain *single-value* map is needed (where multiline value for `5:` overrides the `NONREF` value), `Collectors.toMap` may be used:

```java
Map<String, String> map2 = Pattern.compile("(?m)^ *(\\d+:)(.*(?:\n(?! *\\d+:).*)*)")
    .matcher(s)
    .results()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        mr -> mr.group(1), // trimmed, key includes the colon
        mr -> mr.group(2).trim(),
        (v1, v2) -> v2,
        LinkedHashMap::new
    ));
```

---

**Update**
For Java 8 a simpler solution would be to use `while (matcher.find())` loop to collect the results of regex matching.  Also, the regular expression needs to be tuned to allow for letters in the key part (`\\w+` instead of `\\d+`):

```java
Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();

Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(?m)^ *(\\w+:)(.*(?:\n(?! *\\w+:).*)*)")
    .matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()) {
    map.put(matcher.group(1), matcher.group(2));
}
map.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + "|'" + v + "'"));
```

Output (for the latest input):

```
1:|' AFXSD                                        '
2:|' TNBLO                                                '
13:|' ONHDSAD                                                 '
51:|' NONREF                                                           '
25:|' 213213234                                                    '
32:|' ASD3123,01                                                    '
5:|' /ASDAS321                         abc      
      91360070 AVENIDA ENGENHEIRO ARY DE  ABREU LIMA N 900 PORTO ALEGRE
      BRASIL                                                           '
52A:|' ASDSADDASSA                                                      '
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, just in my code change 5: is not repeat, it is only once, will it code work for this?

Comment: Do you mean that untrimmed strings are used as keys so that `"  5:"` and `" 5:"` are different?

Comment: Sorry my input is wrong, 5: is only once, I have updated input

Comment: Then, it should work fine, the first solution provides the lists containing only one item; for the second solution the merge function won't be triggered, and the code will work fine.

Comment: I am using Java 8, will this code supports for java 8?

Comment: As I mentioned, `Stream<MatchResult> Matcher::results` is available since Java 9.  You may check the update compatible with Java 8 using plain `while` loop.

Comment: Thanks Alex, Your previous code is working but my input is coming whole data in one line like 1: AFXSD                                    2: TNBLO                    5: /ASDAS321                         abc      .how can we separate this code?

Comment: @arun, a couple of things.  First, this is definitely another question -- because the original question has explicit `\n` characters, and it is not clear how the multiline address is presented now, so you should post this as a separate question and provide relevant details about your input, actual output, and expected output.  Second, it would be great if you find time to accept/upvote this answer if it's been helpful for you.

Comment: @ Nowhere Man, It is working as per requirement but small change in colon 5: data should come in multiple lines as shown in question, now I am getting colon 5: data in one line

Comment: @arun, please open another question, and provide all relevant details: _your actual code_,  input string, expected and actual result.